# I am getting this strange error on in onAttach(Context)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-context

In `onAttach` function eclipse shows error stating

> The method onAttach(Activity) in the type Fragment is not applicable
>   for the arguments (Context)

although it is clearly Context type variable passed

```
import android.content.Context;

public class MyListFragment extends Fragment{
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview,
            container, false);
        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDetail("fake");
          }
        });
        return view;
      }

      public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onRssItemSelected(String link);
      }

      @Override
      public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
          listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) context;
        } else {
          throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
              + " must implemenet MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
      }

      // may also be triggered from the Activity
      public void updateDetail(String uri) {
        // create a string just for testing
        String newTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // inform the Activity about the change based
        // interface defintion
        listener.onRssItemSelected(newTime);
      }
}
```

Comment: API level that you are using??

Comment: @UsamaZafar  targetSdk version is 15

Comment: Then that is the problem. You are using wrong version of function for your targetsdk....

Comment: @UsamaZafar yep if API<23 den it should be **public void onAttach(Activity context)**

Comment: Yep seems like you got it. Please mark Rohits answer as accepted one so other might get hep from it as well.

Comment: @UsamaZafar  i marked it but it is not visible becoz my reputation is low. please do vote my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using API < 23 then

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
```

should be

```
public void onAttach(Activity context) {
```

See [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.app.Activity%29)

**Note:**

`onAttach(Context context)` was added in api 23. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach%28android.content.Context%29)

Comment: @shruti if it worked then don't forget to accept the answer then please.

Comment: Accepted your answer.Thanks for help again

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem can you try to pass Activity in your `onAtach` method like this:

```
   @Override
      public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
          listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } else {
          throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
              + " must implemenet MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
      }
```

and tell me if it works or not.
Hope to help!

Comment: If my anwer is help you can accept it, if you want of course :)

Comment: no you vote up the answer. Accept is when you click green thick to my answer :) , you can chose to accept only one answer.